# What to do about a user using Stack Exchange logo as Gravatar?

Tags: support

While trolling Stack Overflow, I found a [particular user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/940096/spk) who is using the Super User logo as their gravatar image.  Now, I'm no legal expert, but this seems to be to be a violation of the [Trademark Guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance), since that logo could potentially be used on any other Internet location that uses Gravatar where that user has used the same email address.

*Edit:* The issue I see is that this user might be considered an employee or representative of Stack Exchange in general or Super User in particular on these sites.

What can we do when we see such violations?

Comment: "Trolling" SO or "trawling"?

Comment: We could thank them for the community evangelism...

Comment: Take your pick ;)

Comment: @Kevin The problem, as I see it, is that they could be considered employees or in other ways endorsed by Stack Exchange if that logo is being used on other sites.

Comment: I guess you could custom-mod-flag one of his posts.  If you feel the need to report it, the best thing to do would probably be to e-mail the community team.

Comment: Meh. Pictures are pictures. I think there is a need to act only if that user does something clearly harmful (ie. actually poses as a Super User employee, or insinuates he is one). Based on my past experience with the SO/SE team, their judgement may be a similar one

Comment: I'm no lawyer either, but I doubt the fact that the _logo **could potentially** be used on any other internet location that uses Gravatar where that user has used the same email address_ (bolding mine) is really an issue.

Comment: @Dennis But, the logo is protected by trademarks and the user does not (probably) have specific permission to use the logo as his/her avatar on any website.

Comment: @saluce: But he's using the avatar here. If you discover that he uses it on another website, that would be entirely different.

Comment: @Dennis He or she is...it's on Gravatar.com.

Comment: @saluce: Unless he uses the same email address here and on another website, that's still not an issue imho.

Comment: The big if here is whether or not the user is using it elsewhere. Since we cannot easily determine this, there isn't anything to worry about really. Note that it's easy enough to use unique per-site email addresses for many techies, so it's not a given this user is using the logo elsewhere.

Comment: I think you should change your gravatar.  It appears like you are attempting to impersonate [Pen Jillette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pen_Jillette)